# Build index which will cover queries

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-indexes

The steps in our application are :

1. Tweets are being fetched and stored in a MongoDB collection viz. **search_tweets**
2. Data is read from search_tweets, several parameters are calculated and the results are stored in a different collection viz. **Twitter_Processed**. This collection has far less no. of keys and most of it are calculated fields

Sample document - **search_tweets**

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5372fae4e4b0e6088a20a4f4"),
  "contributors" : null,
  "text" : "Stay far from #Massachusetts General Hospital. It secretly imposes #unilateral #DNRs against patient &amp; family wishes. http://t.co/hDuK96gqyU",
  "geo" : null,
  "retweeted" : false,
  "in_reply_to_screen_name" : null,
  "possibly_sensitive" : false,
  "truncated" : false,
  "lang" : "en",
  "entities" : {
    "symbols" : [],
    "urls" : [{
        "expanded_url" : "http://www.nationalreview.com/human-exceptionalism/377745/unilateral-non-resuscitation-massgeneral-wesley-j-smith",
        "indices" : [122, 144],
        "display_url" : "nationalreview.com/human-exceptio…",
        "url" : "http://t.co/hDuK96gqyU"
      }],
    "hashtags" : [{
        "text" : "Massachusetts",
        "indices" : [14, 28]
      }, {
        "text" : "unilateral",
        "indices" : [67, 78]
      }, {
        "text" : "DNRs",
        "indices" : [79, 84]
      }],
    "user_mentions" : []
  },
  "in_reply_to_status_id_str" : null,
  "id" : NumberLong("466053869173088258"),
  "source" : "web",
  "in_reply_to_user_id_str" : null,
  "favorited" : false,
  "in_reply_to_status_id" : null,
  "retweet_count" : 0,
  "created_at" : "Tue May 13 03:14:35 +0000 2014",
  "in_reply_to_user_id" : null,
  "favorite_count" : 0,
  "id_str" : "466053869173088258",
  "place" : null,
  "user" : {
    "location" : "Gainesville, VA",
    "default_profile" : false,
    "profile_background_tile" : true,
    "statuses_count" : 3978,
    "lang" : "en",
    "profile_link_color" : "E82012",
    "profile_banner_url" : "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/137925469/1353178590",
    "id" : 137925469,
    "following" : false,
    "protected" : false,
    "favourites_count" : 156,
    "profile_text_color" : "E0B392",
    "description" : "Saved by faith in Jesus and ministering at nursing homes with my wife, Germaine.  We pray for the abolition of abortion and all forms of slavery (trafficking).",
    "verified" : false,
    "contributors_enabled" : false,
    "profile_sidebar_border_color" : "FFFFFF",
    "name" : "Lawrence Sylvain",
    "profile_background_color" : "F9F4E1",
    "created_at" : "Wed Apr 28 04:24:00 +0000 2010",
    "is_translation_enabled" : false,
    "default_profile_image" : false,
    "followers_count" : 157,
    "profile_image_url_https" : "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/3150852957/fdfc37190dec1e382a7fe6489a611399_normal.jpeg",
    "geo_enabled" : false,
    "profile_background_image_url" : "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/714440493/0d3e10e0aee5e662fcf3a6a5a686c541.png",
    "profile_background_image_url_https" : "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/714440493/0d3e10e0aee5e662fcf3a6a5a686c541.png",
    "follow_request_sent" : false,
    "entities" : {
      "description" : {
        "urls" : []
      },
      "url" : {
        "urls" : [{
            "expanded_url" : "http://www.LJSConsulting.com/",
            "indices" : [0, 22],
            "display_url" : "LJSConsulting.com",
            "url" : "http://t.co/37QKbkdxpa"
          }]
      }
    },
    "url" : "http://t.co/37QKbkdxpa",
    "utc_offset" : -18000,
    "time_zone" : "Lima",
    "notifications" : false,
    "profile_use_background_image" : true,
    "friends_count" : 331,
    "profile_sidebar_fill_color" : "BE9E78",
    "screen_name" : "ljsylvain",
    "id_str" : "137925469",
    "profile_image_url" : "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/3150852957/fdfc37190dec1e382a7fe6489a611399_normal.jpeg",
    "listed_count" : 0,
    "is_translator" : false
  },
  "coordinates" : null,
  "metadata" : {
    "result_type" : "recent",
    "iso_language_code" : "en"
  },
  "token" : {
    "CONSUMER_SECRET" : "4FsHhU2KuYsbowCJsuZ4RtsUq4rpLQQcQAGeXkIZqY",
    "ACCESS_TOKEN" : "2362487558-EflbK1NLJMjhAQnXQHkmRwMCwqBBlZ2Y0KRnydf",
    "CONSUMER_KEY" : "cmZaUbCeDpb9SWCwUlCNsA",
    "ACCESS_SECRET" : "gNvLl6n3gXwXBl7GZfHpmUMreqNn1OULz30SpT29jAYwy",
    "APP_ID" : "3"
  },
  "searchProfileId" : 905,
  "customerId" : 0,
  "schedularId" : 32446,
  "userId" : "395",
  "subject" : "Massachusetts General Hospital ",
  "context" : "Healthcare",
  "tagId" : 0,
  "domain" : "General",
  "uniqueId" : 933,
  "message" : "Stay far from #Massachusetts General Hospital. It secretly imposes #unilateral #DNRs against patient &amp; family wishes. http://t.co/hDuK96gqyU",
  "searchkeyword" : "Massachusetts General Hospital ",
  "connectortype" : "TWITTER"
}
```

Sample document - **Twitter_Processed**

```
{
  "_id" : {
    "SpId" : 905,
    "Channel_Id" : 0,
    "ActivityId" : "137925469",
    "SchedularId" : 32446,
    "UniqueID" : 933
  },
  "Cust_Id" : " 0",
  "Domain_Id" : " General",
  "searchkeyword" : " Massachusetts General Hospital ",
  "Sentiment" : 0.42,
  "Intention_cause" : "None",
  "Intention_category" : "None",
  "Emotion_category" : "neutral",
  "AgeGroup" : "26-35",
  "Gender" : "M",
  "Location" : {
    "Country" : "United Kingdom",
    "Lat" : "54.7136300",
    "Long" : "-6.2142800",
    "City" : "Northern Ireland"
  },
  "message" : "Stay far from Massachusetts General Hospital. It secretly imposes unilateral DNRs against patient &amp family wishes. httpt.cohDuK96gqyU",
  "PostDate" : ISODate("2014-05-12T21:44:35Z"),
  "DetectedLanguage" : "English",
  "ProcessedText" : "%*Stay*% far from Massachusetts General Hospital . ==0.01:::It secretly imposes unilateralDNRs against %*patient*% &amp family wishes . ==1.25:::httpt.cohDuK96gqy U ==0:::",
  "IdeaCloudText" : " PS_stay PS_patient",
  "IdeaCloudTopicSpoken" : "  Massachusetts General unilateralDNRs patient family",
  "userid" : " ljsylvain",
  "followers" : 157,
  "like_count" : 0,
  "plusone_count" : 0
}
```

After reading the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-indexes-to-support-queries/), how should I build an index/several indexes when:

- In find/$match, keys "searchProfileId" & "schedularId" are used
- The keys "text", "user"(has several sub-documents), "searchProfileId", "schedularId" and "uniqueId", "id_str" are returned
- The "text" has tweets which is random - does it make sense to include it in a compound index? If not, will building a text index help in any way(NO text search is done within the value of "text")

Basically, I want to ensure that the queries are covered.

Comment: This very much looks like a raw feed so here is the point of advice. Try and dissect the data you wish to query and pre-aggregate where possible into different sources. You are actually asking too many questions here for a definitive answer, and you already point out some of the problems with doing so as anything that could be a single answer. You can always ask something less broad as a singular question, but I don't see what the learning value here is from writing a 10 page essay to even attempt to answer what you are asking.

Comment: I have mentioned the keys that I want to query and return, I just need guidance as to how to build index(es). The second collection, as clear from the sample data, has quite clean structure.
Omitted one entire question, only index one kept.
Yes, may be too many questions but I guess they all are imp. for indexing.